# Netbeans IDE Menu showing weired characters and system font Not Working

Tags: java, windows, netbeans, fonts, system

I have changed my system font. **everything in the system works better with the new font**. but **Not java applications or Netbeans IDE**. all the menus and labels in java applications or Netbeans IDE show weired characters and does not use the changed system font.

Please help me in fixing this.

NOTE : **I don't want to change the system font to default** as I don't like at all and that's why I have changed my default system font.

this is how my Netbeans looks like with new font

[image]

this is how a java app looks like

[image]

My system specs are

- Windows 11 64bit
- java version 1.8.0_111
- Netbeans IDE 8.2
- New changed system font is : Manrope (OTF)

Please help how to fix this weired menu display and show the manrope font properly in Netbeans and other Java applications.

**Thanks in advance.**

Answer (score 1):

I have found two solutions.

1. First one is to add the code `-J-Dawt.useSystemAAFontSettings=on` to the `netbeans_default_options` in netbeans config file (After searching alot in internet, found this). **But this only helped with netbeans but not other java applications.** Somehow I assume this problem rose due to the anti aliasing issues with JRE.
2. So as second solution I updated to latest jre version `"1.8.0_321"`. and with this other java applications also worked.

Now after updating JRE the other java application looks like this
[image]

But only problem is that the font seems to be narrow and bold. But for now I can live with that. But **I assume that, this bold font occurred because of font substitution.**

If I can find a solution to substitute with right font then I may fix this issue too. Hope my problem and solution both helps someone..